# Android Open fragment by Intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

i have developed app Android with a query fragment that have 3 steps and at the end can save all parameter query by a click, after when i go to the fragment that have the query saved if i click i open an activity that show directly the result of query this is my code:

```
listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    QueryListAdapter adapter =  new QueryListAdapter(this);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(QueriesActivity.this, CustomListViewActivityQuery.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            FirstProjectApplication.query = FirstProjectApplication.allQueries.get(position);
            bundle.putBoolean("query", true);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Now when i click i would like to open the fragment query and not the activity by Intent.
Any help?

Thanks
Regards

Comment: You cannot open new fragments. Fragments need to be always hosted by an activity.

Comment: So i must change my fragment query into Activity?

Comment: you can replace the previous fragment with new one.

Comment: Check this [tutorial](http://androhub.com/android-pass-data-from-activity-to-fragment/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    QueryListAdapter adapter =  new QueryListAdapter(this);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

          CustomListViewActivityQuery fragment2= new CustomListViewActivityQuery();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            FirstProjectApplication.query = FirstProjectApplication.allQueries.get(position);
            bundle.putBoolean("query", true);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            fragment2.setArguments(bundle);
             FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
             FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
             fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment2);
             fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
             fragmentTransaction.commit();
           }
         });
```

**Noted that the R.id.fragment1 is your QueriesActivity frame layout ID.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example from documentation:

```
// Create fragment and give it an argument specifying the article it should show
ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();  
Bundle args = new Bundle();  
args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);  
newFragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);  
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```